# Context-free pumping lemma of $a^nb^n$

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I know $a^nb^n$ with $n\geq0$ is considered a context-free language, but if I try:

Using pumping length $p = 3$

$n = p$, thus we have $aaabbb$

$u =aa$ and $y = bb$

$v = a$, $w = b$ and $x=λ$, then  $|vwx|=2\leq p=3$ and $|vx| = 1 \geq 1$

$uv^iwx^iy \notin L$, for instance, with $i=2$ we have:
$$aaaabbb$$

I know I'm wrong in some part of the process, that's I'm attempting to 'break' the lemma, to fully understand it.

Comment: The pumping lemma states that there *exists* a decomposition $uvwxyz$ which can be pumped, not that *every* decomposition can be pumped.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus but doesn't the lemma says that if a language fails to be pumped then it wouldn't be CFG? CFGs are excepetions on its own pumping lemma?

Comment: No it doesn’t. It says that if a language is context-free, then every long enough word in the language is “pumbable” with respect to *some* decomposition.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I get it. About the decomposition topic, I'm pretty sure mine is supposed to fit the requirements. Doesn't it?

Comment: Pumpability is one of the requirements. (See my answer below)

Comment: If I pump a supposed CFG and it fails, therefore I would have to try for every case in order to prove it isn't a CFG?

Comment: Yes, you need to establish there exists no legal decomposition of the given string. (The string's length must be at least some pumping length of the language $p$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You picked a wrong decomposition. Similarly to the pumping lemma for regular languages, the pumping lemma for context-free languages states that for every context-free language $L$, there exists *some* legal decomposition for every string $s$ with $|s| \geq p$ where $p$ is a pumping length of $L$.

By legal decomposition, I mean dividing $s$ into partitions $uvwxy$ such that

- $|vx| \geq 1$
- $|uvw| \leq p$
- $uv^nwx^ny \in L$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$

In the case of the string $aaabbb$ with $p = 3$, a legal decomposition would be eg. $u, w, y = \epsilon$, $v = aaa$, $x = bbb$.

Comment: Could you say where my decomposition fails the criteria? I can't see it

Comment: @AkariOozora It fails the third criterion: "pumping" the string does not result in strings of $L$ as you note yourself. If all decompositions fail at least one of the criteria, then the language cannot be pumped.

Comment: but for languages that are not CFG they would also fail for the third criteria, wouldn't they?

Comment: @AkariOozora For every langauge, you can produce *some* decomposition that fails one of the criteria, and that does not prove anything. The pumping lemma states that every sufficiently long string of any context-free language has *some* legal decomposition in this manner. You need to prove no legal decomposition exists, which you haven't done.

Comment: You're using $w$ to mean two different things...

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Excellent point, I'll correct that.